# How to change file attributes by Itamae that exists alreasy in server

Tags: itamae

I want to change file attributes by `Itamae` that exists already in server.

I tried like:

```
file '/usr/local/bin/jobber' do
  action :nothing
  owner 'jobber_client'
end
```

and

```
file '/usr/local/bin/jobber' do
  action :nothing
  user 'jobber_client'
end
```

But both didn't change the file owner.

How can I change file attributes by `Itamae`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should use the :edit action instead of the :nothing one to change the file owner.

```
file '/usr/local/bin/jobber' do
  action :edit
  owner 'jobber_client'
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I could change the owner of the file.